# Standard Output is Empty in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class CandidateCode {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt();
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        int tot=1;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        String[] strs = br.readLine().split(" ");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n; i++){
            tot*=arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(tot);

   }
}
```

*I don't know what's wrong with this code, I get standard output is empty error* **Help Me!**

Input Given:

```
5 

1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The input contains an empty line which read between `s.nextInt()` and `br.readLine()` therefore it cannot be split into numbers.

This input succeeds:

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
120
```

If the purpose of this code is to multiply `n` integer numbers, there's no need to read the line and then split it using extra instance of `BufferedReader`.  Also, array `int[] arr` seems to be redundant.

The following code reads the count of integers `n` and calculates their product:

```java
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = s.nextInt();

int tot=1;

for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
    tot *= s.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("\nproduct: " + tot);
```

Output (integers can be read successfully regardless of whitespaces/empty lines):

```
5
 1 2
3 4
 5
 
product: 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `i < n` with `i < n && i < strs.length` in both the `for` loops. This will ensure that the loops will be executed also as per the length of `strs[]` rather than just `n` number of times, which may cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error in the first loop e.g. for the following inputs:

```
5
80
```

your first loop will try to run from the index, `0` to `4` whereas the length of `strs[]` is `1` in this case i.e. the maximum allowed index, in this case, is `0`.

With just `i < n`, your second loop body will run without `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` but the result will be unexpected when the number of entries in `br.readLine()` is different from `n`. Since all the places in `arr[]` are initialized with `0` by default, the result will be zero when `str.length < n`; on the other hand, when `str.length > n`, the entries beyond the index, `n - 1` will not be multiplied.

You can write `i < n && i < strs.length` also as `i < Math.min(n, strs.length)`.